Gulp Compiling issues
I have picked up a job from a friend, who got their site built from Fiver, I am having Huge trouble compiling ANYTHING, i have tried installing gulp, npm run watch, and neither seem to work.
The files installed are:

gulpfile.babel.js
.babelrc
.stylelintr.json

The Css files are kept within:

Assets > css
css > scss_converted.css
Src > scss > site.css
src > scss > site.scss
src > global > {Range of scss sheets{

I have tried using run dev which i found in the package.json file:
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:vendor-prefixes && npm run build:rtl",
    "build:rtl": "concurrently \"npm run build:rtl-style\" \"npm run build:rtl-esb\" \"npm run build:rtl-esc\"",
    "build:rtl-style": "rtlcss style.css style-rtl.css",
    "build:rtl-esb": "rtlcss assets/css/editor-style-block.css assets/css/editor-style-block-rtl.css",
    "build:rtl-esc": "rtlcss assets/css/editor-style-classic.css assets/css/editor-style-classic-rtl.css",
    "build:vendor-prefixes": "concurrently \"npm run build:vendor-prefixes-style\" \"npm run build:vendor-prefixes-esb\" \"npm run build:vendor-prefixes-esc\"",
    "build:vendor-prefixes-style": "postcss -r --no-map style.css assets/css/editor-style-block.css assets/css/editor-style-classic.css",
    "build:vendor-prefixes-esb": "postcss -r --no-map assets/css/editor-style-block.css ",
    "build:vendor-prefixes-esc": "postcss -r --no-map assets/css/editor-style-classic.css",
    "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style 'style.css' 'assets/**/*.css'",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js 'assets/**/*.js'",
    "lint:pkg-json": "wp-scripts lint-pkg-json"
}

I try npm run build but this only compiles the stylesheets within the assets folder, and nothing else as the styles are put into the src > scss > blocks folder.
And when i try to run gulp after install, i get:
ReferenceError: styles is not defined
I know I've probably made a right dogs dinner of this, but I've tried to figure this out for days and have no contact with the devs and how they set up their compilation.
any help would be so greatly appriciated,

Have validated that you run the same node.js version as expected ? Some npm (read most) are nodejs versions sensitive. I also don't why we talk about gulp here ?
